# Github API and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ajax, github, cors, github-api

this probably is a simple (series of) question(s) but I can't wrap my head around it.

I'm trying to access the github api from a web app hosted on my site. This is the code in a nutshell:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>p { color:red; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax( {url :'https://api.github.com/repos/janesconference/kievIIPlugins/commits', dataType: "json", cache: false, success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            var lastCommitSha = data[0].sha;
            $("p").text("Last commit SHA: " + lastCommitSha);
        }
    });
});
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Ajax request not (yet) executed.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If I point my browser to this simple page uploaded [on my dropbox account](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6767816/ghapi.html) everything is ok.
If, instead, I point my browser to this simple page uploaded [on my site](http://bitterspring.net/ghapi.html), I get the infamous `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` exception:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.github.com/repos/janesconference/kievIIPlugins/commits?_=1360060011783. Origin http://bitterspring.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So, the questions:

- Why does it work on Dropbox?
- I understand that with CORS it would work even on the website. This is a matter of putting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.github.com` on my Apache configuration or something like that. But, as quoted from en.wiki,

> However, this might not be appropriate for situations in which security is a concern

- Is there a way to do this without changing the Apache configuration? Probably, I can't touch the Apache conf of my hosting site, and there's always the security concern. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Dropbox works fine for me. I tried to register a new application, but I frankly don't know what to put on the Callback URL field : ) Can you give me some pointers on how to set up this? (the link you posted doesn't give me any hint)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, looks like my company is filtering all traffic to dropbox as of recently. Will have a look when I get home :)

Comment: This is what I have set-up for my page which is using the GH API:

Name: ivanzuzak.info
URL: ivanzuzak.info
Callback URL: ivanzuzak.info

So, everything is the same if you're just invoking the API from a static page, which is your situation. You actually don't need the callback URL for your usage scenario, since you just want to enable CORS for a domain, and not use OAuth.

Comment: This does the trick. If you put your comment in form of an answer, I'll approve it as the selected answer. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. Wrote up a short answer below :) Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to get CORS working for your site (e.g. http://example.com), you have to enable it by creating a GitHub OAuth application here: https://github.com/settings/applications

Since you are using a GitHub applications to get CORS to work (not using it for enabling OAuth itself), you can just enter your site's URL in all three fields in the "Create Application form":

- Name: http://example.com
- URL: http://example.com
- Callback URL: http://example.com

Note that if you intend to use OAuth functionality, you need to setup Callback URL differently.

After this, you should be able to send AJAX requests to GitHub APIs from your site http://example.com.

Comment: even if it is `localhost` ? cos I cant

Comment: _not using it for enabling OAuth itself_. How does that mean? In my case, I need to call Github API from my site (client-side js). And for that I want my users to authenticate themselves using Github, so that in the process I could get some token to be used by Github API call. How do I do that? I need Github app to be register?