# Axios CORS issue with Github oauth Not getting access token

Tags: javascript, github, oauth, cors, axios

I have created 2 routes on my React-Redux app. I have added github applications settings with homepage and callback URL already.

1.
When you hit this route : https://reduxapp.herokuapp.com/signin
You click on Github login button, ==> **githubGeturi**

2.
Github redirects back with a code https://reduxapp.herokuapp.com/auth/callback?code=9536286a59228e7784a1
and **githubSendCode**('9536286a59228e7784a1') action is triggered

You can see in network call OPTIONS call goes through, but POST call never happens. and you get a console error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=32b70bf671e04762b26c&…_secret=123456789123456789123456789&code=9536286a59228e7784a1. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://reduxapp.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Below is my action functions:**

```
const CLIENT_ID = '32b70bf671e04762b26c';
const CLIENT_SECRET = '123456789123456789123456789';
const ROOT_URL = window.location.origin;
const REDIRECT_URL = `${ROOT_URL}/auth/callback`;
const AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize';
const ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token';
const STATE = _.random(10000);

export function githubGeturi() {
  const GITHUB_URL = `${AUTHORIZE_URL}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=user,public_repo&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URL}`;

  return (dispatch) => dispatch(signinUrl(GITHUB_URL));
}

export function githubSendCode(code) {
  const GITHUB_URL = `${ACCESS_TOKEN_URL}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&code=${code}`;

  axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
  const axiosPost = axios.post(
    GITHUB_URL,
    {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'text/json'
    }
  });

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(signinRequest());
    return axiosPost
      .then(
        success => dispatch(signinSuccess(success)),
        error => dispatch(signinError(error))
      );
  };
}
```

========
The only possible way I found is make POST call with server.
You can view the entire solution here: https://github.com/steelx/ReduxWeatherApp/commit/6215634ca543a4760ea96397fe31b61f22184d91

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of this SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705726/github-api-and-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: This is oauth API issue

Comment: Do NOT post your secret on here!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like you can't make a call to that end point via JavaScript

https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/330

On your example I see that OPTIONS method call fails, and this is because axios does that when you add extra headers to request, but POST call fails as well.

You can setup a proxy in between your app and github on your server which simply forwards your requests and replies with response.

Comment: seems they don't support actual Web flow.

Comment: using a local proxy server, to make ajax call with github is the solution.